# Google map center with document.getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, java

I cant use php echo to call the two coordinates to center the map and with getElementById does not work, what is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("Focus")),
zoom:5,
};
var map=new
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>

<div id="Focus" type="text" value="45.2527,27.61234">45.2527,27.61234</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP in your sample. You are also trying to use the whole `<div id="Focus">` element as a property, that's not going to work like you think.

Comment: div's don't have `value` ... and `new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("Focus"))` will pass the div element to `new google.maps.LatLng` ... which expects a lat/long, not an HTML element as arguments

Comment: p.s. java has nothing to do with javascript - so, tag fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myMap() {
    var arr=document.getElementById("Focus").getAttribute("value").split(",")
    var mapProp= {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(arr[0],arr[1]),
    zoom:5,
    };
    var map=new
    google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
```